# Copy JSON only copies half of the JSON

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm using Webstorm's debugger to inspect local variables for my Node application. However, when I right click on the variable I'm interested in and click `Copy JSON`, the pasted output only contains half of the JSON.

Has anyone experienced this issue and what did you do to resolve this? Yes, I could console.log the data or write it to a file, but I figured that using a debugger would be more efficient.

Thanks in advance,
Q

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I have seen this too. Not sure what causes it. Here is a workaround:

Try switching to the console tab and saving variable out as a JSON string as follows:

```
JSON.stringify(myvar);
```

Then copy the results and, if necessary, parse it elsewhere with:

```
JSON.parse('..data goes here..')
```

Don't forget to use single quotes because the JSON contains double quotes everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up and work around. I tried finding the issue on web storm's issue tracker pager but no dice. I've created an issue if anyone's interested: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19933

Comment: Np. Hopefully they fix it. Strange limitation!

Comment: switching to console doesn't actually work for me, it get's cut off as well.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use Evaluate Expression in the right click menu and then copy the JSON.stringify results from there.

Comment: This turns out to be a node.js version issue (see the issue tracker mentioned above).  Upgrading node fixed this for me!